# Getting Undefined when taking values out of an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print individual values from an array but it doesn't seem to work (get undefined). When i print out the array itself it shows that values are contained in the array at index 0 and 1.

```js
let imgDim = [];
imgDim.push(300);
imgDim.push(300);
let width = imgDim[0];
let height = imgDim[1];
let testString = "s994320";
if (/^[ms]\d+$/.test(testString) == true) {
    console.log(imgDim); //works
    console.log(width, height); //undefined undefined
}
```

Comment: If the syntax error in the declaration of `testString` is fixed (the value should be a quoted string), your code works properly.

Comment: What is the data type for s994320 ?

Comment: @EvanGertis I think that's supposed to be a quoted string.

Comment: Click Run code snippet and you'll see the error.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if the actual code had that error, the first `console.log()` would not work.

Comment: oh sorry it is in my code but i forgot to add the .toString() here. I will just edit it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @IshSah. OK, well as you can see your code does work.

Comment: sorry everyone i forgot to add quotes. Just edited it

Comment: well if it works in that case then why does it not work here. Thats where i am confused.

Comment: @IshSah. your most recent edit does show the issue but it's *not* a problem with the array - it's because [the `load` callback is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is error at let testString = s994320;

```
let imgDim = [];
imgDim.push(300);
imgDim.push(300);
let width = imgDim[0];
let height = imgDim[1];
let testString = 's994320';
if (/^[ms]\d+$/.test(testString) == true) {
  console.log(imgDim); //works
  console.log(width, height); //undefined undefined
}
```

```js
let imgDim = [];
imgDim.push(300);
imgDim.push(300);
let width = imgDim[0];
let height = imgDim[1];
let testString = 's994320';
if (/^[ms]\d+$/.test(testString) == true) {
  console.log(imgDim); //works
  console.log(width, height); //undefined undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by adding the quotes to *s994320* the code works :

```js
let imgDim = [];
imgDim.push(300);
imgDim.push(300);
let width = imgDim[0];
let height = imgDim[1];
let testString = "s994320";
if (/^[ms]\d+$/.test(testString) == true) {
  console.log(imgDim); //works
  console.log(width, height); //undefined undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const imgDim = [];

imgDim.push(300);
imgDim.push(300);

const [
  width,
  height,
] = imgDim;

const testString = 's994320';

if (/^[ms]\d+$/.test(testString)) {
  console.log(imgDim);
  
  console.log(width, height);
}
```